# sushi rice vs pudding rice

Tags: rice, sushi

I've done sushi a couple of times, successfully I must stress, and while in sainsbury looking for it I came across the pudding rice which looks exactly the same as the more expensive sushi counterpart. I found another thread here [What is the best rice for sushi?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21872/what-is-the-best-rice-for-sushi?newreg=1991095460a74927a5c7691b2f9e81ab) saying essentially the same thing, but not many people posted in it, so I was wondering if anybody else has tried it. Any idea?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7976/67

Answer (score 4):

So, just a quick update as it seems i forgot about all this. I eventually did it and used pudding rice for the sushi and it gave good results. Granted, I'm not a sushi maniac, or sushi trained l, meaning, somebody who's really into it perhaps will spot the difference straightaway. But to me it tasted and felt pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

Any Japanese rice will give you good results. Sushi rice is different from ordinary Japanese rice in the cooking technique - it uses less water to compensate for the vinegar. Some varieties of rice are sold specifically as sushi rice, but these tend to be much more expensive than ordinary rice.

You can often find good rice in Korean grocery stores, but rice from south east Asia - Thailand, Indonesia, etc. is different, and doesn't make as good sushi.

Specifically with regard to pudding rice, I suggest you try it. However, cooks illustrated found that pudding rice has a slightly more firm and distinct texture that was slightly off for sushi. Better would be to check your local Asian grocery store for Calrose rice - Botan brand can be ordered online, Nishiki rice is better, but can be hard to order. These are ordinary, every day rice that make good sushi.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the suggestions. I've bought the pudding rice this morning, and I'll be making sushi this weekend, I will update this thread with the results using the pudding rice, just to try. Next time I will buy one of those you suggested, just to check how the sushi comes out :- )

Comment: Closer substitution: sushi rice vs risotto rice. Once accidentally used sushi rice in a risotto, it came out fine.

Comment: Yup - Risotto is usually made with arborio rice, which is also very short grain and soaks up a lot of liquid. However, the reverse substitution isn't very good, since it leads to a strangely sticky, gummy texture.

Answer (score 2):

I have been asked to make sushi by my 6year old boy. There are no assian shops where i live so i used the risotto rice. The texture was similar. I used 1 part of rice to two cups of water. At the bottom of the pot rice was slightly mashed and , so i used mainly the rice at the top of the pot for sushi. I hope the family will aprove it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my little bit, I use pudding rice for risotto and it works very well, and again the Italian aficionados out there would probably tell the difference, but to me it is very good and less than half the price. But I am anticipating trying it for Sushi also and now feel a lot happier that it may just work. Thank you.